# how can i upload multiple files to azure blob using python flask for web development

Tags: python, flask, azure-blob-storage, flask-wtforms, flask-login

im working on web development and im in the starting stage of it . i have created a website , in that website there is an html page asking to upload files ,im trying to upload the multiple files to azure blob at once but only the 1st file is getting uploaded .

here is the code of html:

```
enter code here


<div class="card" style="width:400px">
<div class="card-body ">
  <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    
    <input type="file" name="file" value="file">
    <input type="file" name="file1" value="file1">
    <hr>
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success">
  </form>
  {{msg}}
</div>
```

here is the code for python :

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename  and \
         filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in allowed_ext 
      

@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])

def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        img = request.files['file']
        if img and allowed_file(img.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(img.filename)
            img.save(filename)
            blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container = container, blob = filename)

            with open(filename, "rb") as data:
                try:
                    blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
                    msg = "Upload Done ! "
                except:
                    pass
            os.remove(filename)
       
        
    return render_template("dashboard.html", msg=msg)
```

i want those 2 input files of html to be uploaded in the azure blob but in my case only one 1st input file is getting uploaded.

when i try to upload the 2nd file leaving the 1st file empty im getting an error saying:
UnboundLocalError
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

- You can just call the `request.files` twice to get the other file.

```
app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])

def  hello():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_file = request.files['file']
        Second_file = request.files['file1']

    return  first_file.filename+" "+Second_file.filename

app.run()
```

My Html file would render like this :

[image]

the output would be this

[image]

- Also, you can just add the retrieved file directly in the `upload_blob`  method to upload it to the blob storage.
- Also make sure you have Storage data contributor role so that you can upload blobs